# ASP MVC to multiple IIS (Deploy)

Tags: asp.net, .net, iis, deployment

Is there a way to deploy an ASP MVC application with the same config but to multiple IIS (different server, but same URL) ?

I have to deploy the same project to multiple IIS application, of course with Visual Studio One Click Web Publish it's OK, but in my case I have more than 10 deployment to do.

So is there a way, like a script with PowerShell or something else?

Comment: MS Web Deploy and Config Transforms.  Great article! [You're deploying it wrong! TeamCity, Subversion & Web Deploy part 1: Config transforms](http://www.troyhunt.com/2010/11/you-deploying-it-wrong-teamcity.html)

Comment: Hi Lankymart, yep I tried that but in my case and like some other people said it in the comments of this article, I have more than 10 deploy to do with the same project and the config it's not the problem in my case, but publish 10 times by VS is a little bit boring :s

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally I don't find any good and nice way but what I did ; I created a web.config file for each IIS server (because there were little difference between them) and after I use the config transform option of VS.

Then I created a publish config in VS for each IIS server and select the correspondig web.config file.

And with the one click publish bar of VS, when I select a publish config, it automatically load the right web.config file and publish the app.

It's not the best idea but it works fine.

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar issue and ended up writing a custom app.  I don't know of anyway to handle this automatically with any MS tools.